# Authorizing Google Charts to access private spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a Web App using Google Apps Script to query data from my Google Sheet using [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/).

I have been able to successfully query the spreadsheet when the Google Sheet is publicly shared, however since the spreadsheet contains confidential info I would rather do it privately using [authorizations](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#authorization).

The reason why I want to use Google Charts visualisation functions (as opposed to the server side Spreadsheet App) is because of the speed of querying large data sets.

I have tried following the steps in the above documentation. That is, creating a client id then using the gapi.auth library to authenticate myself but I continue to receive an error.

When i add the authorization library and first part of the code from the documentation (with console.log simply to see where it get's up to):

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/auth.js?onload=init"></script>

<script> 
var clientId = '1234.apps.googleusercontent.com'; 
var scopes = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds';       

function init() { 
  
console.log("here");  
  
gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true},handleAuthResult);

}

</script>
```

I receive the following error:

> 1289869776-mae_html_user_bin_i18n_mae_html_user.js:41 dropping
> postMessage.. was from unexpected window

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Rubén, yes I am using Apps Script.

Comment: Hi Ruben, the web app will have a 'timeline' chart with filters to dynamically change the timeline, so my ultimate goal was to be able to extract the data as quickly as possible using query language. Google Charts visualisation permits this from the client side. Using server side code requires me to obtain the data range (SpreadsheetApp) then loop though the range values to obtain the exact data I need.

Comment: Plus, the data contains a large amount of dates, so transferring it from server to client requires me to loop through the data again to reconstruct the dates.  Does that make sense or am I overcomplicating things?

Comment: Getting the whole data set is not the issue. The issue is the time it takes to get a subset of the data ( based on what filters have been input by the user in the web app). Query language allows me to very quickly get this subset of data, however the SpreadsheetApp doesn't have this ability so I am left looping through endless amounts of data to construct a data table.

Comment: Unless there is a way to query data from the server side that I am not aware of. I'll keep searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are creating your web app using Google Apps Script, it's not necessary to "authorize Google Charts to access private charts" because you could use Google Apps Script services and methods to get the data from the spreadsheets and pass them to Google Charts.

On [Converting from UiApp + Chart Service to Html Service + Google Visualization API](https://mogsdad.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/converting-from-uiapp-chart-service-to-html-service-google-visualization-api/) it's shown how to convert the old dashboard example from from UiApp + Chart Service to HtmlService + Google Visualization API. This illustrates how to create a Google Apps Script web app that builds a chart from Google Spreadsheet data without "requiring authorization" as it's "implicitly" handled by Google Apps Script.

From the above link

> Two functions cooperate to retrieve the dashboard’s data and display it. As soon as the visualization API is loaded, the sendQuery() function is invoked. **Using the google.script.run facility, it sends its request to the server-side getSpreadsheetData() function**. This is an asynchronous operation, so two callbacks are provided, a successHandler and a failureHandler. One or the other will receive the result of the server call, depending on the outcome.

H/T to [jfllmartin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1482604/jfllmartin), author of an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32000617/1595451) to [Converting my google dashboard app from the UI service to the HTML service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29226100/1595451) where the above link was shared.

Related

- [How to create google dashboard including piechart and range select filter from a spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27854303/1595451)
- [Display Spreadsheet data in Sites with Html Service](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16660906/1595451)

Comment: Thanks Ruben, really appreciate all your help on this one. Dashboard controls is what I was missing and hopefully will be quick to update large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

can I suggest you change from using Google sheets to using firebase with Google sheets or just Firebase, and then with Google appscript in the back end.

I often use a Google script to problematically update Firebase with data from the Google sheet. I then enjoy the speed and security of Firebase to deliver a super fast user experience.

There are two go to pages for using Firebase in appscript. The example [page](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase) and the [quick start](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script).

Furthermore, I gave up using Google's own charting library and starting using high charts or chartJS, as they are more accessible.

Comment: Hi Jason, whats the difference between Firebase and Google Cloud SQL in this instance. Is it purely storing the data temporarily to be queried again?

Comment: Yes. It can be a temporary store of the data or a longer term solution. My experience shows that Google sheets are okay until they hit about 100+ thousand rows then performance starts to suffer when making quires. I don't know about Cloud SQL expect unlike Firebase and sheets there is a fee to use it.